# Core Bluetooth scan for peripherals does not work time to time

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I used this method `- (void)scanForPeripheralsWithServices:(nullable NSArray<CBUUID *> *)serviceUUIDs options:(nullable NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options;` to start scan my peripherals. But sometimes it does not work. I don't receive callback that peripherals found time to time.

Start scanning from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` seems does not work all the time.

Comment: You need to show more code

Comment: Does it initially discover devices and after a while it stops or the callbacks are not called as often as you would expect?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I can fully answer since you provided only a small snippet of code. But:
1. scanForPeripheralsWithServices looks only for the peripherals with that particular service. Others aren't found. For more - check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889321/scanforperipheralswithservicesoptions-unable-to-connect-when-specifying-servic) 
2. To find all peripherals I suggest using the didDiscoverPeripheral method in conjunction with the didDiscoverServices to find all peripherals and then pick one with the service you want. 
Hope it helps!